# Rails tutorial chapter6 has_secure_passwordの動作が解説と一致しない

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Rils tutorial 6章で躓いており、教えていただきたいです。

6.26にhas_secure_passwordを追加すればテストがパスするようにあると書いて有りますが、パスしません。

```
Failures:

1) User when password is not present 
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
       expected #<User id: nil, name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", created_at: nil, updated_at:     nil, password_digest: "$2a$04$P8/lQ.ytJHrnRbPM..Z4qeUAIipdMNjbOtohvnJI/31..."> not to be valid
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.36208 seconds
25 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69 # User when password is not present 

Randomized with seed 52215
```

このテストを逆にshoud be_validにすれば通ります。こういうものでしょうか？

参考までに使用したテストの全文です。

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

    before do
        @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
            password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
    end

    subject { @user }

    it { should respond_to(:name) }
    it { should respond_to(:email) }
    it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
    it { should respond_to(:password) }
    it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }

    it { should be_valid }

    describe "when name is not present" do
        before { @user.name = " " }
        it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when email is not present" do
        before { @user.email = " " }
        it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when name is too long" do
        before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
        it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when email format is invalid" do
        it "should be invalid" do
            addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
            addresses.each do |invalid_address|
                @user.email = invalid_address
                expect(@user).not_to be_valid
            end
        end
    end

    describe "when email format is valid" do
        it "should be valid" do
            addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org frst.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
            addresses.each do |valid_address|
                @user.email = valid_address
                expect(@user).to be_valid
            end
        end
    end

    describe "when email address is already taken" do
        before do
            user_with_same_email = @user.dup
            user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
            user_with_same_email.save
        end
        it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when password is not present" do
        before do
            @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
                password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
        end
        it { should_not be_valid }
    end

    describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
        before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
        it { should_not be_valid }
    end
end
```

Comment: いやぁ。出先なので検証できていませんが「こういうものでしょうか？」は、明確にNoです。has_secure_passwordによって、パスワードの空白(" ")がエラーになるのが正しいので should_not be_validでパスする必要があります。まずその1点だけコメントします。

Comment: suzukisさんの回答にコメントをぶらさげました。 できれば使用しているrailsのバージョン(rails -vで確認できます)も追記していただけますか？

Comment: コメント、ありがとうございます！
$ rails -v
Rails 4.2.0
でした

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
describe "when password is not present" do
    before do
        @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
            password: " ", password_confirmation: " ")
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
end
```

`has_secure_password`自身は文字長や文字種はチェックしておらず空白文字1文字だけのパスワードでも許容するので、`has_secure_password`を追加しただけなのであれば`password`と`password_confirmation`ともに空白一文字を指定している上記のテストは失敗するのではないでしょうか。

---

コメントで指摘があったとおり、Rails4.2より前は空白のみのパスワードが検証に通らないので「テストが失敗する」のを再現するのであれば4.2より前のバージョンを使えばいいということになります。

Comment: あ！ Rails4.2からの変更点。これかもしれません。 `has_secure_password がデフォルトで空白のパスワードを許容するようになりました (例: 空白スペースのみのパスワード)。`
See: http://railsguides.jp/4_2_release_notes.html

Comment: rails 4.2　でした！

rails4.2で言えばこのテストはvalidなんですね。以前のバージョンでrails newしてここまで勧めるのは大変なので、その作業は割愛します。

ありがとうございました！

Comment: また、tutorial6.29でパスワードの文字数制限を加えます。この時点で問題のテストは通るようになるようです。情報まで。

Comment: Railsチュートリアルを進めていくときに、気付かないうちに違うバージョンで `rails new` してしまう方が多いようです。先日この問題に関する解説記事を書いたのでよかったら参考にしてみてください。 http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/f3bde6e46afbeba8cb82

Answer (score 0):

User側の実装も見てみないと何とも言えませんが、単純にnameに正しくバリデーションが付いていないのではないでしょうか？
たとえば`validates`ではなく、`validate`になっているとか。（僕もこれに何度かハマったことがあります）

というわけで一度Userの実装も追記してください。

あと、デバッグの方法としてrails consoleでトライアンドエラーを繰り返すというやり方があります。

```
u = User.new 
u.valid?
u.errors
```

みたいにしながらコンソール上でnameの値をいろいろ変えてみてください。

不可解な動きをする場合はコンソールの操作内容も追記してください。